# Copy and pasted items won’t show up in the scene

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I have a nature Scene in one blend file and an animation and a couple other meshes in another blend file. When I try to copy and paste this over into the main scene the items pasted pop up appears however non of the items appear. What can I do to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Do the pasted objects show up in the outliner? Are the origin points of the pasted items compatible with where you want them in the scene? Or, are the pasted objects at a location that you need to move around in the viewport to find them? If the latter, just move the objects to where you want them in the scene.

Comment: The pasted object do not show up in the outliner. I’ve been copy and pasting the items back and forth to work on the animation without lag, and sadly on the final time it would no longer paste. and they’re not in the viewport.

Comment: Is the Copy Attribute addon enabled? Or use the File > Append operation instead?

Comment: Hey I finally got it because of you thank you so much